# Place, date, signature in one line

Tags: rules

I want to put the place on the left side, the date on the center and the signature on the right side. And above them, a line should come. I am trying this on Sharelatex. I couldn't control the alignment and the names [image: Expected Output]

My Code looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={180mm,266mm},
 left=15mm,
 top=14mm,
 }

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.4em}  


\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\makeatletter% since there's an at-sign (@) in the command name
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  %\parindent=0pt% don't indent paragraphs in the title block
  {\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}\@author\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}\raggedleft\@date\end{minipage}}
  \par
  \centering
  {\Large \bfseries\textsc{\@title}}
  \HRule\par%
}
\makeatother% resets the meaning of the at-sign (@)

\title{Motivation Letter}

\author{}

\date{}


\newcommand{\namesigdatehrule}[1]{\par\tikz \draw [black, ultra thick] (0,0) -- (#1,0);\par}
\newcommand{\namesigdate}[2][5cm]{%
\begin{minipage}{#1}%
    \vspace{1.0cm}\namesigdatehrule{#1}\smallskip
    \small \noindent\textit{Signature}

\end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Lorem lipsum...

\namesigdate{} \namesigdate{} \namesigdate{}
\end{document}
```

And my output is like this:

[image: my output]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX Stackexchange. Can you explain, please, why the tags are: `bibtex` and `pdftex`?

Comment: The simple solution would be to copy the definition of `\namesigdate` (the `\newcommand{\namesigdate}[2][5cm]{...}` bit) and replace `Signature` with `Place` and `Date`.

Comment: @moewe Thank you for your edit. I didn't edit for several reasons.

Comment: @moewe would you give me the code for alignment?

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you need three lines with equal length and with `\quad` space between them. The lines fill the width of the typesetting area. Each line has a word below at left side of the line and with one space. It can be done as follows:

```
\def\sign#1{\rlap{\lower2.7ex\hbox{ #1}}\leaders\hrule\hfil}
\hbox to\hsize{\sign{Place}\quad \sign{Date}\quad \sign{Signature}}
```